# android sdk manager doesn't show any updates

Tags: android

When I first ran SDK manager it had loads of options to download, I installed API 15 and 10, I need the support package installed to start a new project and the only thing that shows up now are the currently installed packages.  Nothing new shows up.  I'm using repository 7.  Any ideas?

My main concern is that after updating I can't start a new project because I'm missing the android support libraries, I can't get the support libraries because the downloader won't update the list.

Comment: Sometime it does not show up instantly, you need to wait by the time all the new updates is shown to be installed.

Comment: It says done loading packages pretty quickly, I'll see what happens.

Comment: No luck, it never changes the list, just shows the installed packages.

Comment: Do you have the Checkbox checked that says Updates/New and not just the one that says Installed?

Comment: Yep, I even unchecked installed.  I'm thinking its maybe the wrong URL but it doesn't error out.

Comment: I'm having this same error. Can't see any packages that I haven't already installed something from. Have all those checkboxes checked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem, found the solution here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/wp8FFGmsgAQ

> Clear your cache and reload. The clear-cache button is in Tools > Options in the SDK Manager, and reloading is Packages > Reload in the SDK Manager.

Comment: I still have problem and new SDK won't shown. my eclips version is Version: 3.7.2

Answer (score 0):

Try quitting Eclipse and then opening the SDK Manager directly. This worked for me.

Comment: it ended up being the https url, though I never got an error saying it couldn't connect. I changed it to http and it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

Go to "Tools > Options" and set up the Proxy Settings. Hope it helps

Comment: Can you give more details in what the settings should be?

Comment: You have to ask you network administrator. Usually it's a server in your internal network. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

it is the problem we face many time in eclipse.
to solve this problem you need to Clear your cache and reload. 
just follow below given step

### open AVD manager

The clear-cache button is in Tools > Options.
and reloading is Packages > Reload in the SDK Manager.
also seled first check box in other category which force https insteam of http.
restart AVD and Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Try to **Restart Adb Server**, that's how I've made that.

If using VS2015, it could be found under "Tools -> Android" menu.