# Android Development Tools SDK Manager doesn't fetcch updates and new packages?

Tags: android, adt

I'm trying to install the API 20 ABI. When I open the SDK manager UI, I only see installed packages, and nothing to install (the ABI images are not even in the list -- it's whatever that comes with the ADT by default). When I use the command line to update, using `android update sdk --all --no-ui`, this is what I get:

`Refresh Sources:
  Fetching https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml
  Fetched Add-ons List successfully
  Refresh Sources
  Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-10.xml
Refresh Sources:
  Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-10.xml
There is nothing to install or update.`

But this is not true. I haven't installed any CPUs for any APIs.

Also, when I set the SDK UI to show me the packages group by repositories, I only see `Local Packages`.

What's wrong?

Edit: I forgot to mention that I've both tried the command above using `--no-https`, and through the SDK manager by checking the box that says `Force https://... sources to be fetched using http://...` No luck.

Comment: I edited my question to include the http and https results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear the SDK manager cache. SDK manager --> Tools --> options --> clear cache 
Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13450569), it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

In Android SDK manager, under tools -> options, enable force https to http, close the SDK manager and reopen. See if that fixes this issue. [Another user reported similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25813579/how-do-i-install-system-images-for-android-4-4w-api-20/25814181).

Comment: Forgot to mention that I've already tried that one per another question on StackOverflow.

Comment: what is your SDK manager revision. For system images, SDK manager is supposed to fetch https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android/sys-img.xml . In your log, it seems to be stopping right after repository-10.xml , there are few other xmls it will need to fetch.

Comment: That is the problem. It also seems to make a request three times, as if it couldn't connect, or timed out the last time. However, even the `android -v update sdk --no-ui --no-https` command doesn't give me any success or failure messages after those requests.

Comment: can you click on the link in my previous comment and see it open in browser ? just want to rule out your system having problem connecting to google download site. If you can see it browser, i am guessing your current SDK manager installation could be corrupted. I would give the [standalone SDK manager a try](http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r23.0.2-windows.zip)

Answer (score 0):

Verify if this option is checked

[image]

Comment: I'm blind and thus can't see that image, but if you mean `Force https://... sources to be fetched using http://...`, yes, it's checked.

Comment: in SDK Manager UI, bellow packages list and left to button "Install packages", there is label `"Show: [x] Update/New [X] Installed [ ] Obsolete...."`

Comment: Ah. I've checked all three checkboxes, and I still only see `Local Packages` when sorting by repository, and nothing new when sorting by `API level`.